# How to concat two fields of a CSV file and print the result to a file?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file:

```
field1, field2
a,b
c,d
...
```

I want to check if both values are positive integers, and if so, concatenate them and write to output file. I was messing with awk for a while, but it doesn't work and produce any output at all.

So, if the input is

```
1234,5678
123,asdf
123a,999
111,2222
```

Expected output is:

```
12345678
1112222
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: but you have written, check if numeric , what does this line means ?

Comment: @PS. I have added an example

Comment: When you say "numeric" do you mean "whole numbers" (i.e. positive integers)? You don't show any non-integer or negative numbers in your sample input/output so YMMV with the solutions you get if your real input can contain `3.14` or `.2` or `-1` or `0x3` or `4e2` or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was that sed would provide the simplest solution:

```
sed -Ene '/^[0-9,]+$/s/,//gp' input.txt
```

(Note that your sed may require `-r` instead of `-E`. Check `man sed` for details.)

The same thing could be achieved with awk, of course.

```
awk '/^[0-9,]+$/ {gsub(/,/,"");print}' input.txt
```

Note that as I've written these, they should handle any number of fields, and there isn't any protection against empty fields. If you want to restrict yourself to lines with just two non-empty fields, that should be a simple regex change:

```
sed -Ene '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/s/,//p' input.txt
```

or

```
sed -ne '/^[0-9][0-9]*,[0-9][0-9]*$/s/,//p' input.txt
```

or

```
awk '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ {sub(/,/,"");print}' input.txt
```

These solutions avoid the consideration of "fields" by simply treating the entire line as a pattern. If you'd prefer to parse fields, you're out of luck with sed, but you could do this with awk:

```
awk -F, '$1 $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ { print $1 $2 } input.txt
```

(Note that in this last awk command line, all the spaces except the one after `print` can be removed without affecting functionality. But for the sake of the sanity of your future self, don't compress things just to save a few bytes. There's no performance difference, and making things unreadable always delays your repair of broken processes in the future.)

And of course, you have the option of not using awk at all. Everything we're doing here could be done in bash alone.

```
while IFS=, read x y; do [[ $x$y =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "$x$y"; done < inp
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

{
    if( NR == 1 )
        next

    for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
        printf "%s", $i

    print ""
}

# end-of-file #
```

One line:

```
$ awk -v FS="," '{ if(NR>1){ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ printf "%s", $i } print ""} }' input.txt
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
awk -F ',' '{if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) print $1$2}' yourCSV
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ awk -F ',' '{if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ ) print $1$2}' input.csv
12345678
1112222
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{if($1 ~/^[0-9]+$/ && $2 ~/^[0-9]+$/) print $1 $2}' infile
12345678
1112222
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements seem quite unclear, but I'm guessing something like this.

```
awk -F, '/^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ { print $1 $2 }' file.csv
```

The regex checks if the line contains two integers with a comma between them; if so, we print them adjacent to each other, without any field separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if both fields can be converted to numeric and concat if so:

```
awk -F, '$1+0==$1 && $2+0==$2 {print $1 $2}' file
```

This support floating, negatives, etc as well as integer fields.

Or, just detect what you don't want and skip them:

```
awk -F, '/[^0-9,]/{next} {print $1 $2}' file
```